# Convert dictionary values inside a column of a Dataframe to new separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file, and I have put it in a pandas dataframe:

| no | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"age": "30", "sex": "male"} |
| 2 | {"age": "26", "sex": "female"} |

I would like to create two new columns named 'age' and 'sex' (the dict. keys), then drop the original column so that it looks like this:

| no | age | sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | male |
| 2 | 26 | female |

How can I create those two new columns automatically using data from the dictionaries inside of the column 'data'?

Comment: So data is a dictionary or a string?

Comment: Use `json_normalize`, see duplicate

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert the `dict` like column to `dict` with `ast`

```
import ast
df = df.join(df.data.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(x))))
df
Out[69]: 
   no                            data age     sex
0   1    {"age": "30", "sex": "male"}  30    male
1   2  {"age": "26", "sex": "female"}  26  female
```